# IOS CGContextDrawImage zoom the image, efficiency is very low

Tags: ios, opengl-es, bitmap, draw

I use CGContextDrawImage zoom the image, but when I Shrink it the efficiency is very low,
Is there any way or to change improve efficiency.

```
//bitmap is 1000X1000 when i Shrink it use CGContextDrawImage
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(cbx, cby, image.size.width-X, iamge.size.height-Y),[image CGImage]);
//X and Y increased gradually
```

Comment: I understand English is not your primary language, but what you have written makes no sense. You need to clarify your question. Is the problem that if you want to draw the image at full resolution, but the image is so large you run out of memory?

Comment: I have changed my problem.thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at CGContextRef, there is an option to set the interpolation quality - you want it low for speed: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(...); You can also try to use the Accelerate functions (look at vImage related functions specifically), but its not clear this is going to help make it all that much faster (and there is a learning curve here).

If you can shrink it by powers of 2, you can do this resize yourself by taking every other pixel every other row - that will be very very fast.

Also, every time you shrink the image, cache that image, and if you have to resize to a smaller image use the previously shrunken image and not the huge one as a starting point.

Comment: thank you very much ,Although not reaching I want efficiency,  enough to solve our current problems